# Running script before shutdown seemingly not working

Tags: ubuntu, init-script, sysvinit

I created a small script `backup_files.sh` and placed it in `/etc/init.d`:

```
#/bin/sh
logfile=/media/verbatim/log
date >> $logfile
rsync -av /home/philipp/Documents /media/verbatim/ >> $logfile
```

I would like this script to be executed whenever the computer is rebooted or shut down, so I did the following:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/backup_files.sh /etc/rc0.d/backup_files.sh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/backup_files.sh /etc/rc6.d/backup_files.sh
```

Moreover, I made the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/backup_files.sh
```

I tried the script "manually" and it worked just fine. However, if I shutdown or reboot my computer, it is apparently not executed.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm using Xubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found out that I had to give them particular file names:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/backup_files.sh /etc/rc0.d/K10backup_files.sh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/backup_files.sh /etc/rc6.d/K10backup_files.sh
```

The scripts in /etc/rc0.d and /etc/rc6.d are executed at the time of shutdown and reboot respectively. The scripts with their name starting with capital `k` are executed with an argument `stop` while those starting with capital `S` are executed with argument `start`. Moreover the execution of files is done in lexicographical order.

The files in these runlevels are named as:

```
[K | S] + nn + [string]
```

nn -> a two digit number
string -> **must** be a **lowercase** string

More about linux runlevels can be found [here](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/212/An_introduction_to_run-levels)